# how to use seq2seq to decode concatenated string

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, recurrent-neural-network, seq2seq

Am trying to decode a concatenated String like below ...

```
 SQCB7A750BATWE SQ CB 7 A 750 B A T WE 
 PT05A1219PY023 PT 05 A 12 19 P Y 023  
 PT55A1019PX02  PT 55 A 10 19 P X 02  
 PT33SE2215SW023    PT 33 SE 22 15 S W 023  
 PT05A2216PW023(LC) PT 05 A 22 16 P W 023 (LC)
```

am looking for a smarter way rather than hard-coded rules as the input will have variations(number of characters and digits), I came across `SEQ2SEQ` model and I want to know if it's possible to use it in such problem
I already followed some tutorials to get a taste of it, but the results weren't even close
it also seems there are 2 approaches character level and word level as per [this tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/nlp-sequence-to-sequence-networks-part-1-processing-text-data-d141a5643b72)

Character level:

```
Input sentence: SQCACA333BA71A
Decoded sentence: P 9(PDD366AZ2IDD4K )F)F(L)L)1)1)1)        6A
-
Input sentence: SQCAAC152DA71A
Decoded sentence: P 9(PDD366AZ2IDD4K )F)F(L)L)1)1)1)        6A
```

am still trying to implement the word level, but I'd like to know if the problem can be solved using this approach (seq2seq)

Comment: Do you have a fixed number of possible words?

Comment: no, because the number of words varies on the input, and this is won't be fixed

Comment: I mean in the vocabulary. Do you know how many possible words you have in the vocabulary?

Comment: @xashru, no, won't be known